# CSS: Duplicate Styles or Keep the Same

Tags: html, css

I have following CSS below for Top and Lower button row boxes. Sometimes, I duplicate CSS , because style and design may change in future. And Two row orientations may differ.

Generally, should I a) create duplicate css styles, so future developers can customize, or b) is it best practice to tightly couple into one, until UX may change design later?

```
.top-button-row {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.lower-button-row {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Example: two rows may not be `justify-content: space-between` in future.

Comment: Why not just use one class for all rows with those styles and add another class for customized rows where needed?

Comment: what if they differ in the future? they may not be justify-content: space-between in the future? isnt it still tightly coupling? just curious, thanks

Comment: Then I would suggest taking out anything from that first class that wouldn't be common, and adding it into another class to use where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to have a common class between the two elements, so that they can be styled together *and* individually:

```
<div class="button-rows">
  <div class="button-row top-button-row">...</div>
  <div class="button-row lower-button-row">...</div>
</div>
```

```
.button-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.button-row.top-button-row {
  color: red;
}
.button-row.lower-button-row {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: what if they differ in the future? they may not be justify-content: space-between in the future? isnt it still tightly coupling? just curious, thanks

Comment: In that case you'd remove `justify-content` from the common class (and add it into one of the individual classes, if there's a specific element that needs it). From a maintainability standpoint I don't think you'll do any better than this!